# Convergence of nth root of sum of nth potence of positive real numbers

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, summation

Let $k \in N$ and $a_1, a_2, ..., a_k > 0$. Prove that the following series $(b_n)$ converges and define its limit.

$$b_n := \sqrt[n]{\sum_{i = 1}^ka_i^n}$$

I'm quite sure it converges to something between $min(a_i)$ and $max(a_i)$, but don't really know where to start. Sandwich theorem wasn't of much help as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean to say $a_k$ is also a positive infinite sequence, because as of right now, your question reads that $a_k$ is the last value for some fixed $k$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the limit of $\sqrt[n]{\sum_{i=1}^m |x_i|^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031556/finding-the-limit-of-sqrtn-sum-i-1m-x-in)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1188476/42969.

Comment: @HansLundmark That was it, tnank you!